# Why is .submit() not working on changeDate with Bootstrap Datepicker?

Tags: jquery, forms, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I am using [Bootstrap Datepicker](https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker) and I want to submit a form with the new date value when the new date is selected - so no submit button.

My form HTML is:

```
<form id="date-form" method="post" action="" accept-charset="utf-8" >
<input data-date-autoclose="true" data-date-start-view="months" data-date-format="M yyyy" data-date-min-view-mode="months" type="text" id="date-input" />
```

I have this posting the form OK:

```
$('#input-date')
    .datepicker()   
    .on('changeDate', function(){
        $('#date-form').submit();
});
```

However I need to get the new date value so have this:

```
$('#input-date')
    .datepicker()   
    .on('changeDate', function(e){

        $('#date-form').submit(function() {

            var date = $('#input-date').val();

            $.post("my-page", function() {
                alert("success with posting " + date);
            });

             // even if I just have console.log("worked"); in here it wont log

        });
});
```

With the above code a POST request is not made at all. As I mention I can't write to the console either.

How can I get the form to post?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first example you are submitting the form.

The second example you are assigning a function to the submit event. It is not going to submit the form. You would have to call .trigger("submit"); to execute it.

I think you just want

```
$('#input-date')
    .datepicker()   
    .on('changeDate', function(e){    
        var date = $('#input-date').val();    
        $.post("my-page", function() {
            alert("success with posting " + date);
        });
    });
```

Comment: Thanks - that works (seems like such a stupid question now!).

Answer (score 0):

`setTimeout` will be called after Datepicker have updated the value in the input:

```
$('#input-date')
    .datepicker()
    .on('changeDate', function(e){
        setTimeout(function () {
            $('#date-form').submit();
        });
    });
```